# How to modify a nullable type's value?

Tags: c#-4.0, nullable

```
public partial class L2SEntity {
    public void Scale(double d) {
        if (this.Amount.HasValue)
            this.Amount.Value *= d;
    }
}
```

Results in the following error:

```
Error   2   Property or indexer 'System.Nullable<double>.Value' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

How do I change the Amount's (type of double?) value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign it directly.

```
public partial class L2SEntity {
    public void Scale(double d) {
        if (this.Amount.HasValue) {
            this.Amount *= d;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or one too few `{`. :-)
Corrected.